# Prism Event not working in release mode

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am using Prism in my WPF application.

I have subscribed to an Event.

```
 _iEventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Unsubscribe(AddSubscription);
 AddSubscription = _iEventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe((i) =>
 {
                Added(ViewModel, i);
 });
```

Publish the event in some other class. It is working fine in the Debug mode. But While switching to the release mode it is not working fine. i.e The subscriber method not gets hit in the source and the part is not executed.

How to check this issue, Is there any way to know my subscription is successful and overcome this issue.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills: Thanks for the comment, My application is big and I will try to provide a minimal code block for replicating the issue and it will be great if I receive any quick suggestion on further checking this issue.

Comment: @mm8: I  have updated my question, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the subscriber is alive (that is, constructed and not garbage collected) when the event is published.

The subscription alone will not keep the subscriber alive unless you subscribe with `keepSubscriberReferenceAlive: true`.

Edit:

If you use the `EventAggregator` to keep your subscriber alive, be sure to dispose of the subscription when it's no longer needed, otherwise you introduce a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, After setting the property to true, it works. But why it is not working in release mode only. For debugging mode without setting the property itself is working.

Comment: Garbage collection might be more aggressive in release mode, or you keep a reference around in debug mode only...